# Принципы построения API

Tags: php, java, node.js, ruby-on-rails, api

Хотелось бы получить наводки на ресурсы\книги, где можно систематизировать знания по построению правильного API. Так-то свои API я делал, строил на laravel. Но хотелось бы делать это действительно систематизированно и правильно. Без привязки к конкретному средству реализации - это дело последнее. Можно на английском, но комфортнее было бы всё же на русском.

Comment: Вот принципы создания от Microsoft (English - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design, Русский - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design)

Answer (score 1):

Самыми популярными, на сегодняшний день, являются SOAP, REST и CRUD API. Думаю, пары статей с википедии о том, что это за разновидности и общих правил разработки вполне хватит для реализации большей части потребностей в современной api архитектуре

Comment: @SonicMyst точно. Видимо, проголодался, когда это писал. Поправил. Спасибо

Comment: Хотел сам поправить, но уже все сделали)